# Making a Query after a Post method in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm doing a Post method on a URL, and therefore is supposedly begin written on a Database. I want to , inside the test tab on postman, make a "if" to check the status of the response and after that make a query to verify that the content sent is there. This is possible to make it work on postman?
Because with that its easier to run the collection and verify that the method is working in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have a feature like that in postman. If you need to perform operations based on the response, then you need to do something in code. 
You can make the functionality in the route you hit a reusable service and have a separate route to perform checks so that you could get the response of the route you hit by invoking the service in the new route.

Comment: When you say "route", you mean what?

Comment: I mean the URL of the service @RenatoEiras